# How to extract tasks and variables from a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rake

I need to:

1. Open a Rakefile
2. Find if a certain task is defined
3. Find if a certain variable is defined

This works to find tasks defined inside a Rakefile, but it pollutes the global namespace (i.e. if you run it twice, all tasks defined in first one will show up in the second one):

```
sub_rake = Rake::DefaultLoader.new
sub_rake.load("Rakefile")
puts Rake.application.tasks
```

In Rake, here is where it loads the Makefile:

> https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/rake_module.rb#L28

**How do I get access to the variables that are loaded there?**

---

Here is an example Rakefile I am parsing:

```
load '../common.rake'
@source_dir = 'source'
desc "Run all build and deployment tasks, for continuous delivery"
task :deliver => ['git:pull', 'jekyll:build', 'rsync:push']
```

---

Here's some things I tried that didn't work. Using `eval` on the Rakefile:

```
safe_object = Object.new
safe_object.instance_eval("Dir.chdir('" + f + "')\n" + File.read(folder_rakefile))
if safe_object.instance_variable_defined?("@staging_dir")
  puts "   Staging directory is " + f.yellow + safe_object.instance_variable_get("@staging_dir").yellow
else
  puts "   Staging directory is not specified".red
end
```

This failed when parsing `desc` parts of the Rakefile. I also tried things like

```
puts Rake.instance_variables
puts Rake.class_variables
```

But these are not getting the `@source_dir` that I am looking for.

Comment: Can you provide an example Rakefile? Hard to say otherwise (ie if the var gets defined in a task, is that valid? Should you be able to identify this purely from syntax, or might it construct the value dynamically, requiring you to actually run it? If you can tell from syntax, probably just parse the file (parser and ruby_parser gems can both do this), otherwise, you might have to evaluate the file. But really, based on the var name, its probably best to pull this out into some sort of configuration file and then use that file from both the Rakefile and your script.

Comment: Thanks, just added the example file. I am now checking out `ruby_parser` to see if that will work.

Comment: I updated to show what I had tried, and also showed the exact line in Rake that is responsible for getting loading the file. But I have no idea of how to get at the those variables that are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
rakefile_body = <<-RUBY
load '../common.rake'
@source_dir = 'some/source/dir'
desc "Run all build and deployment tasks, for continuous delivery"
task :deliver => ['git:pull', 'jekyll:build', 'rsync:push']
RUBY

def source_dir(ast)
  return nil unless ast.kind_of? AST::Node

  if ast.type == :ivasgn && ast.children[0] == :@source_dir
    rhs = ast.children[1]
    if rhs.type != :str
      raise "@source_dir is not a string literal! #{rhs.inspect}"
    else
      return rhs.children[0]
    end
  end

  ast.children.each do |child|
    value = source_dir(child)
    return value if value
  end

  nil
end

require 'parser/ruby22'
body = Parser::Ruby22.parse(rakefile_body)
source_dir body # => "some/source/dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rake runs `load()` on the Rakefile inside `load_rakefile` in the [`Rake` module](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/rake_module.rb#L28). And you can easily get the tasks with the public API.

```
Rake.load_rakefile("Rakefile")
puts Rake.application.tasks
```

Apparently that `load()` invocation causes the loaded variables to be captured into the `main` `Object`. This is the top-level `Object` of Ruby. (I expected it to be captured into `Rake` since the `load` call is made in the context of the `Rake` module.)

Therefore, it is possible to access instance variables from the `main` object using this ugly code:

```
main = eval 'self', TOPLEVEL_BINDING
puts main.instance_variable_get('@staging_dir')
```

---

Here is a way to encapsulate the parsing of the Rakefile so that opening two files will not have all the things from the first one show up when you are analyzing the second one:

```
  class RakeBrowser
    attr_reader :tasks
    attr_reader :variables

    include Rake::DSL
    def task(*args, &block)
      if args.first.respond_to?(:id2name)
        @tasks << args.first.id2name
      elsif args.first.keys.first.respond_to?(:id2name)
        @tasks << args.first.keys.first.id2name
      end
    end

    def initialize(file)
      @tasks = []
      Dir.chdir(File.dirname(file)) do
        eval(File.read(File.basename(file)))
      end
      @variables = Hash.new
      instance_variables.each do |name|
        @variables[name] = instance_variable_get(name)
      end
    end
  end
  browser = RakeBrowser.new(f + "Rakefile")
  puts browser.tasks
  puts browser.variables[:@staging_dir]
```

Comment: I found this by using `ObjectSpace.each_object do |the| the.instance_variables.each do |var| puts var end end` to find that the variable did exist *somewhere*.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I am using this here: https://github.com/fulldecent/Sites